# c# using Magento REST api to display product information

Tags: c#, rest, magento, authentication

I created a windows form app and have been looking for a way to pass authentication to connect to the server and retrieve product information.

Couldn't find any examples anywhere. Can someone help me?

[Here is the api link.](https://github.com/nickvane/Magento-RestApi)

Answer (score 1):

If you check out this link you might get everything you need:

```
https://github.com/nickvane/Magento-RestApi/wiki/Authentication-steps
```

Usage of the library can be found here:

```
https://github.com/nickvane/Magento-RestApi
```

(just scroll down a bit)

So in order to authenticate your code, you can use:

```
var client = new MagentoApi()
    .Initialize("http://www.yourmagentourl.com", "ConsumerKey", "ConsumerSecret")
    .AuthenticateAdmin("UserName", "Password");
```

or the other variants that exist in the last above link.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code below. I think it will help you

```
var client = new MagentoApi()
                   .SetCustomAdminUrlPart(AdminUrlPart)
                   .Initialize(StoreUrl, ConsumerKey, ConsumerSerect)
                   .AuthenticateAdmin(AdminUserName, AdminPassword);

            var filter = new Magento.RestApi.Models.Filter();
            //filter.FilterExpressions.Add(new FilterExpression("name", ExpressionOperator.like, "L%"));
            filter.PageSize = 100;
            filter.Page = 0;
            // var response = await client.GetProducts(filter);
            var sCode = Task.Run(async () => await client.GetProducts(filter));
            MagentoApiResponse<IList<Magento.RestApi.Models.Product>> product = sCode.Result;
```